# Convert a list of strings to a list of single-element sets

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I have below list

```
list_of_dict = [{'flat': ['103'], 'wing': u'C'}, {'flat': ['102', '104'], 'wing': u'B'}, {'flat': ['105'], 'wing': u'D'}]
```

I wish to convert into

```
list_of_dict = [{'flat': [{'103'}], 'wing': u'C'}, {'flat': [{'102'}, {'104'}], 'wing': u'B'}, {'flat': [{'105'}], 'wing': u'D'}]
```

Flat should be list of numbers enclosed in '{ }'

Comment: Can't you just loop over it yourself?

Comment: By enclosed in `{}` you mean they should be singleton sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does exactly what you want,

```
list_of_dict = [{'flat': ['103'], 'wing': u'C'}, {'flat': ['102', '104'], 'wing': u'B'}, {'flat': ['105'], 'wing': u'D'}]

for e in list_of_dict:
    e['flat'] = [{x} for x in e['flat']]

print(list_of_dict)
```

**Update:**
The following code should work based on your comment below,

```
list_of_dict = [{'flat': ['103'], 'wing': u'C'}, {'flat': ['102', '104'], 'wing': u'B'}, {'flat': ['105'], 'wing': u'D'}]

for e in list_of_dict:
    e['flat'] = ['{'+x+'}' for x in e['flat']]

print(list_of_dict)
```

Comment: Thank You for reply but i do not want in to be set ,i need it list of string [ '{ 102 } '] ,currently it is [set(['103'])

Comment: Check out the update above which now creates a list of strings containing {}

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want lists of single-element sets, you can use a `for` loop:

```
for d in list_of_dict:
     if 'flat' in d:
         d['flat'] = list(map(lambda x: set([x]), d['flat']))
```

The `if` check here provides an added level of safety, in case your dictionaries do not contain `flat` as a key. Alternatively, using the EAFP approach, you may use a `try-except` brace:

```
for d in list_of_dict:
     try:
         d['flat'] = list(map(lambda x: set([x]), d['flat']))
     except KeyError: 
         pass
```

---

```
>>> list_of_dict
[{'flat': [{'103'}], 'wing': 'C'},
 {'flat': [{'102'}, {'104'}], 'wing': 'B'},
 {'flat': [{'105'}], 'wing': 'D'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

A `{}` denotes a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). Assuming this is what you want, you could do like this:

```
for x in list_of_dict:
    x['flat'] = Set(x['flat'])
```

this will edit the `list_of_dict` to this:

```
[{'flat': Set(['103']), 'wing': u'C'}, {'flat': Set(['102', '104']), 'wing': u'B'}, {'flat': Set(['105']), 'wing': u'D'}]
```

If you type `{'103'}` in your Python interpreter, it will give you this back:

```
set(['103'])
```

This is why I assumed you needed sets.

Comment: What is `Set`?.

Comment: This does not make singleton sets as requestd, but puts all numbers in `flat` into one set together

Comment: A `Set` is an unordered collection of unique elements

Comment: @schwobaseggl according to the desired output this is what the OP asked for... or not?

Comment: The OP wants `[{'102'}, {'104'}]`, not `{'102', '104'}`.

Comment: oh, got it I'm sorry. So he wants each number in a single set?

Answer (score 0):

Comprehension that will do what you need as well:

```
list_of_dict = [{'flat': ['103'], 'wing': u'C'}, {'flat': ['102', '104'], 'wing': u'B'}, {'flat': ['105'], 'wing': u'D'}]
result  = [{k: ['{}{}{}'.format('{',item,'}') for item in v] if k=='flat' else v for k, v in d.items()} for d in list_of_dict]
#[{'flat': ['{103}'], 'wing': u'C'}, {'flat': ['{102}', '{104}'], 'wing': u'B'}, {'flat': ['{105}'], 'wing': u'D'}]
```

Comment: Thank You for reply but i do not want in to be set ,i need it list of string [ '{ 102 } '] ,currently it is [set(['103'])]